# how to import contacts into my flutter sms sender app?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am actually trying to send SMS to my phone contacts and I did build the app based on this code https://github.com/rodrigoc85/flutter-sms-dispatcher I am trying to import contacts from my phone with the user permission to send SMS.

Please can someone tell me if it's possible and how ?

Many thanks .

Comment: Check this: https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service). Here's a code sample taken from its documentation:

```dart
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';  

// Get all contacts on device
Iterable<Contact> contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
```

The `Contact` object has a property `phones` which contains all phoneNumbers saved for the contact.

You can grab the phone number like this:

```dart
// Get phone numbers for the first contact in list.
Iterable<Item>? phones = contacts.first.phones;

if (phones != null && phones.isNotEmpty) {
  String phoneNumber = phones.first.value
}
```

With `Item` class being for contact fields which only have a label and a value, such as emails and phone numbers. And implemented like this:

```dart
Item({String? label, String? value})
```